# Automatically remove Set-Cookies

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, apache2

I have a php web application. This web application sets some cookies.

I want to write a .htaccess which remove on the fly this cookies.

Here is what I've done, with mod_header:

```
Header unset Set-Cookie
```

It works fine, but I have a problem: This line removes ALL the cookies. I want to allow one cookie. Is it possible to filter the cookies by name ?

I have tried to do it with RequestHeader, but I need to work on the response header...

Thanks

Comment: The reasonable approach would be to fix the PHP scripts.

Comment: Thanks but this is not possible. I have also tried mod_ext_filter